# How to Show Live Tracking Polyline in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, annotations, mapkit, tracking

I want to show live tracking in Map View.I am having latitudes and Longitudes List in separate Array… How to Show this in Map as a point.. Please anybody HelpOut For this Problem.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
     let location1 = locations.first as! CLLocation

    // Have to get OldLocation And New Location From API
    let oldCoordinates = location.coordinate
    let newCoordinates = location1.coordinate
    var area = [oldCoordinates, newCoordinates]
    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &area, count: area.count)
    mapView.add(polyline)

    self.currentCLLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newCoordinates.latitude, longitude: newCoordinates.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: self.currentCLLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    print("Location Update Details")   
    print(location.coordinate.latitude)
    print(location.coordinate.longitude)
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location1.coordinate
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)    
}
```

Values In Array:

```
Latitudes Array==>>
["12.988415", "12.988445", "12.988492", "12.988558", "12.988673", "12.988788", "12.988903", "12.989039"]
Longitudes Array==>>
["80.218386", "80.21839199999999", "80.218422", "80.218461", "80.218515", "80.218547", "80.21860100000001"]
```

1. How to Loop the latitude and Longitude Values in Location and Location1 Variable?
2. DidUpdate Method is not getting called Every time we update map?
3. How To show Polyline based on Lat and Long?

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error while compiling/running this code? Or does it behave unexpectedly? If so, what is the current behaviour and what is the expected one?

Comment: I want to show Location Point in map one by one whicjh is in list. For example, am having 7 latitudes and 7 longitudes in array means, from the first i have to show 7 points in map with polyline

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is wrong with your current code? Moreover, where do you even get those arrays from. In your code you are not printing any arrays.